# JQuery : Get image element from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In JQuery, How can i get image element from url?

For example,

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput"/>
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
```

Here its is done via file picker in html5. But, how could i get image from just url?

My requirement is to get image from url.

```
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');  //instead of this how could i get element from url
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');


    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var imageType = /image.*/;

        if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            //save to file api  
        } else {
            fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "File not supported!";
        }
    });
```

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: do you want to display the image or just create a `Image` object

Comment: Not to just display, i need to save it in file api html5.

Answer (score 0):

Do like that:

var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');  //instead of this how could i get element from url
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

```
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var imageType = /image.*/;

    if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (function(file){
                           return function(e){
                                    // do something
                                  }
                        })(file) 
       reader.readAsDataURL(file):
    } else {
        fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "File not supported!";
    }
});
```

[Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: Thank you. And I am sorry, if my question isn't clear. My requirement is to read image from url. Here it is accepting image from file picker.